# SwaggerUI exposing Dictionary<string,string> type in the wrong way

Tags: servicestack, swagger-ui

Dear Overflowers I'm using SwaggerUI for exposing my servicestack REST service specification but I've encountered an unexpected issue.

One of my services accept a request made like

```
    [Route("/MyService/GetStuff", "POST")]
public class GetStuffRequest : IReturnVoid
{
    public string SearchString { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string,string> ParameterArray { get; set; }
}
```

But this is the way SwaggerUI is exposing the request object:

```
GetStuffRequest {
ParameterArray (Dictionary`2[[String`),
SearchString (string)
}
Dictionary`2[[String` {
Comparer (IEqualityComparer`String`),
Count (int),
Keys (Dictionary`2+KeyCollection[[String`),
Values (Dictionary`2+ValueCollection[[String`),
Item (string)
}
IEqualityComparer`String` {
}
Dictionary`2+KeyCollection[[String` {
Count (int)
}
Dictionary`2+ValueCollection[[String` {
Count (int)
}
```

Why does this happens? Can i fix it someway?

Peace&Code 2 you all